# Azure AD B2C Sign In with Apple: Invalid web redirect url

Tags: ios, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am implementing sign in with apple through azure AD B2C on a Xamarin cross platform app. We already have azure AD B2C set up with local accounts. I am just trying to get the option to sign in with Apple working so the app isn't rejected by Apple.

So far, I have followed the instructions here:

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-with-apple

My return url defined within the Apple Service Id is in the format: https://yourtenant.b2clogin.com/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp

When I add the identity provider to my sign up and sign in user flow and run (test) the user flow within the azure portal with the return url: 'https://yourtenant.b2clogin.com/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp'. It loads the up the login screen where I can tap 'sign in with Apple'. From here I am then taken to the Apple login screen.

However, if I tap the option to login with apple on a actual device (iOS/Android) I get the error 'invalid_request' 'Invalid web redirect url' instead of the Apple login form?

I have double and triple checked that everything is setup correctly (That I can see). I have spent quite a while googling around the problem but nearly all the answers just say to check the return url and make sure it's in the format described above.

Does anything need to modified in the app's code to make the sign in with apple option work?

Any help is greatly appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: Hi @Jhardy When the Xamarin app initiates the Azure AD B2C flow that presents the login UI, what is the B2C URL? Does it begin with `https://yourtenant.b2clogin.com/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/`? If not, then when you click the "Sign in with Apple" button, then the redirect URL that is passed from Azure AD B2C to Apple won't match `https://yourtenant.b2clogin.com/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp`.

Comment: I didn't find a solution in the end. We didn't actually implement login with apple. We are awaiting feedback from apple to determine if we need it as we don't use social logins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the return URL that Apple is expecting? Regardless of what Microsoft says it should be? I had this issue also and have answered it for my specific problem here >> [Apple error "Invalid web redirect url." during Azure B2C user login flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69334877/apple-error-invalid-web-redirect-url-during-azure-b2c-user-login-flow)